# Jquery mobile is blocking downloading from my django based site

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-mobile, django-templates, django-views

I have a download link on my site (Django based), that worked fine until I started using jQuery-mobile.  Now when I attempt hit the download link the jQuery-mobile loading screen appears and hangs indefinitely with the loading icon rotating.

I have tried running just without jQuery and jQuery-mobile, and the download works. I have also tried just with jQuery and no jQuery-mobile and the download works.

With all that in mind it seems that it is a problem with jQuery-mobile's page loading function, but I have no idea where to start and if that was the case I would expect to see lots of similar problems when I google it.

Just incase it helps here are the headers from the file download view:

```
content_type = 'application/force-download'
response['Content-Length'] = file_size
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file_name
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the corrections highlighted by BluesRockAddict's answer, but I am still experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most satisfactory of work rounds, but I found that if I have the download open in a new tab by adding target="_blank" to my link, it then downloads without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a typo in content_type, it should be:

```
content_type = 'application/force-download'
```

Also, last line is missing %:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file_name
```

Comment: The lesson here is dont write questions when its late and you are tired :)  I have updated the question with your corrections.  I am still getting the original problem though.